# CMS Database Integration

Tags: drupal-views

I am a beginner of civi crm, and for views integration I have refered this link 
https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/

```
Configuration
If you have your Drupal and CiviCRM in separate databases adding CiviCRM support to Views takes a small bit of configuration. Views must be told where to look for CiviCRM data. Administer > System Settings > CMS Database Integration shows some code that must be copied and pasted into the Drupal settings.php
```

This section is not visible in my cicvicrm CMS Database Integration

It shows no query .. something need to enable this to work?Please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have the Drupal Views module enabled.  If it is not enabled then the settings are not shown on the CMS Database Integration page.